# Router in between modem and computer not discoverable

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, wireless-router

I live in a communal situation, and several years ago a former roommate set up the network like so:

- The combined modem/router from the ISP is has wifi turned off, then two routers are plugged in and broadcasting a wifi network.
- Router 1 is next to the modem and working fine. It can be accessed at 192.168.1.1 when a device is connected to it.
- Router 2 (an older Linksys wrtp54g) is on the other side of the house (via ethernet) and has a desktop, laptop, and several mobile devices connecting regularly, but I can't access it.

It almost seems like the second router doesn't have an IP address. Running ifconfig/ipconfig on the connected devices gives a default gateway IP of 10.0.0.1 which is the IP of the modem. When I run traceroute/tracert, the first hop goes to 10.0.0.1 as well. Connecting to the manufacturer's default IP address (192.168.15.1) times out. If the modem recognizes the router, it lists it by MAC address. Any ideas on how I get my computers to recognize this device so I can log in and check some settings?

Comment: Of course it doesn't work like this. The 2nd router creates a new network and thus shields everything off. The device itself gets an ipaddress, but thats it. A router creates a network. You have a network within a network. If you want to use this setup, put some tape over the wan port of router 2, and put its cable into one of the LAN ports.

Comment: I believe it's already set up like that. The ethernet from the modem is going into a LAN port and three other lines are going out.

Comment: Also, even if I had a network within a network that doesn't explain why I'm having a hard time logging into the second router.

Comment: Ah, if its setup like that, then its logical. The router part is bypassed, but it will be operational. If the ip address is 192.168.15.1 you will need to set a manual ip address on your machine in its range in order to access its settings.

Comment: Are you sure the second one is actually configured as a router and not an access point in bridged mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second router has been repurposed as an AP. This probably means that the Ethernet connection is connected to a LAN interface and DHCP has been turned off. It's thus acting more like a switch then a router.

It probably has an IP address, but it won't appear in a traceroutes (and could be anything theoretically).  You have a fair chance of finding it if you port scan your subnet. It could very well be one of the lowest or highest is in the range - but it is conceivable it's not even in the 10. range - in which case the easiest solution would be to factory reset it and set it up again, disabling DHCP.